# How to return FluentValidation error code to controller?

Tags: c#, controller, fluentvalidation

I have a project that has several layers. Of those layers, I have the Application Layer, where I have my CreateCommand and I also have a Web Layer that contains my controller.

My CreateCommandValidator in Application Layer looks like this:

```
    public CreateCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.Firstname)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithErrorCode("ERR1234");
    }
```

In my StartUp.cs, I have added the below:

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddFluentValidation(fluentValidation => 
fluentValidation
.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("MyCustomers.Application")));
```

When testing through Postman, I do get the error - FirstName should not be empty.

But It does not return the error code ERR1234. I would also want it to send this error code to the controller as a bad request. Is this feasible and any hints on how to do it please?

Comment: Some controller action code would be nice to understand the problem.